# What does preserve-order and group-by-instances mean in testng?

Tags: testng

I can't find the detailed explanation of what those two specifications mean in testng. Can somebody explain it? Check the code below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<test name = "Test1"  group-by-instances="true" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
        <class name = "com.facebook.tests.SignUp_Test_Factory"></class>
    </classes>
</test>
```

public class SignUp_Test_Factory {

```
WebDriver driver;
FacebookMainPage fbMainPage;
HashMap<String,String> singUpMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
@Factory(dataProvider = "signUp", dataProviderClass = PagesData.class)
public  SignUp_Test_Factory(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
    singUpMap.put("firstName", firstName);
    singUpMap.put("lastName", lastName);
    singUpMap.put("email", email);

}
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    fbMainPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, FacebookMainPage.class);
}

@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
public void teardown(){
    this.driver.quit();
}
@Test
public void loadPage(){
    fbMainPage.loadPage();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "loadPage")
public void fillFirstName(){
    fbMainPage.setText_FirstName(singUpMap.get("firstName"));
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "fillFirstName")
public void fillLastName(){

    fbMainPage.setText_LastName(singUpMap.get("lastName"));
}
@Test(dependsOnMethods = "fillLastName")
public void fillEmail(){

    fbMainPage.setText_EmailMobile(singUpMap.get("email"));
}
```

}

```
public static Object[][] signUp(){
    return new Object[][]{
            {"jason","ni","nijinxin527@hotmail.com"},
            {"@#$%@","@#$@#","@#$$%%^@"},
            {"Lee","wang","wLee@gmail.com"}
    };
}
```

What does "group-by-instances" and "preserve-order" do here?

Answer (score 5):

About `preserve-order`, the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html) says:

> By default, TestNG will run your tests in the order they are found in the XML file. If you want the classes and methods listed in this file to be run in an unpredictible order, set the preserve-order attribute to false

And the [xml description](http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd.php) says:

> @attr preserve-order If true, the classes in this tag will be run in the  same order as found in the XML file.

So we can say `preserve-order="true"` is maye useless here. But it looks like it sometimes help to run tests in the expected order. (TestNG issue somewhere?)

---

About `group-by-instances` the [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependent-methods) says:

> By default, dependent methods are grouped by class. For example, if method b() depends on method a(), TestNG will not run b() until all the instances have invoked their a() method. This behavior might not be desirable in certain scenarios, such as for example testing a sign in and sign out of a web browser for various countries.